# Python Replacing missing values ​in lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

Good afternoon, I had a rookie problem that I can't solve
If I want to create a list from the values ​​of the comparison of 2 initial lists by inserting a symbol in the missing places. As I would do it?

```
List1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
List2 = [[1, 3, 6], [3, 5], [2, 3, 5]]
ListFin = [[1, -, 3, -, -, 6], [-, -, 3, -, 5, -], [-, 2, 3, -, 5, -]]
```

Comment: Please post examples as text - preferably as running code. There is no "missing place" in a list - all values must be some sort of object. You seem to have put in dashes... but that's not real code.

Comment: You may need to use `None` or other object as the padding object.